# What exactly happens when I throw an exception myself with a parameter string? When does the toString method get called?

Tags: java, exception

I'm really having difficulty understanding how exception handling works.
Why is it preferable to extend `Exception` instead of `Throwable` class for my own user defined exceptions?

```
try {
   //some SQL exception
} 
catch(SQLException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

What does `e` actually represent here? I knows it is a reference to SQL exception object but what will it print? Does it call the `toString` method?

Edit : The output I get is very different when I override the `toString` method and when I remove it entirely from my source code. Please explain why?

```
class MyException extends Throwable {
  private int detail;

  MyException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "MyException[" + detail + "]";
  } 
}
```

```
class ExceptionDemo {
  static void compute(int a) throws MyException {  // cant be thrown as throwable 
    System.out.println("Called compute(" + a + ")");
    if(a > 10)
      throw new MyException("MyException class error");
    System.out.println("Normal exit");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      compute(1);
      compute(20);
    } catch (MyException e) {
      System.out.println("Caught " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not preferable to directly extend `Throwable`, ever.  And yes, `println` just calls `toString()` on all objects.  It'll print the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: *"Why is it preferable to extend throwable instead of Exception class for my own user defined exceptions?"* What makes you think it is? (It isn't.)

Comment: Edited. Wrote it opposite.

Comment: @markspace If I supposedly don't have a toString method overridden in my user defined exception class then what happens?

Comment: It still really isn't.  Probably you should be extending `IOException` or `SQLException` with your own type.  But if a library method just throws `SQLException` then you should just use that.

Comment: If you don't override `toString()` then the `toString()` from `Throwable` is used, which prints a stack trace as I said.  That's the magic of inheritance, and that's how all objects work.  Exceptions aren't different.

Answer (score 3):

<s>> Why is it preferable to extend throwable instead of Exception class for my own user defined exceptions?</s>

It isn't. You've edited the question to reverse that to:

> Why is it preferable to extend Exception instead of Throwable class for my own user defined exceptions?

Because in general, exceptions should be `Exceptions`; the clue is in the name. :-) `Throwable` is not an exception, it's a throwable. (That said, the `Throwable` / `Error` / `Exception` / `RuntimeException` hierarchy in the JDK is generally regarded as poorly laid out. For instance, it's strange that `Throwable` and its subclasses are checked, and its subclass `Exception` is checked, but *its* subclass `RuntimeException` is not, and there's this other `Throwable` subclass, `Error`, which is also unchecked. I believe it's that way for historical reasons, not because it's great design.)

For your own exceptions:

- Extend `Exception` (or one of its subclasses other than `RuntimeException`) if your exception should be *checked*.
- Extend `RuntimeException` (or one of its subclasses) if your exception should be *unchecked*.
- In the ***very*** unlikely case you're writing code that fits the definition of an `Error`, you might subclass that or one of its subclasses, but I don't think I've ever seen a codebase with an `Error` subclass. Mostly, `Error` is for JVM-level errors like "out of memory."

> ```
> try { //some SQL exception} 
> catch(SQLException e) {System.out.println(e);}
> ```
>
> What does e actually represent here? I knows it is a reference to SQL exception object...

Yes, it's a instance of SQLException or subclass thereof.

> ...but what will it print? Does it call the toString method?

Yes, indirectly: [`PrintStream#println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) calls [`String.valueOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)), which calls `toString` on the object.

> The output I get is very different when I override the toString method and when I remove it entirely from my source code. Please explain why?

Because your `toString` isn't implemented the same way `Throwable`'s `toString` is implemented. You're also doing a different `println` than you initially showed (one using string concatenation), although it doesn't make a big difference. Your instance's `toString` is used regardless.

Comment: Could you please review my new code in the post? Thanks.

Comment: @Whateversuitsyou - I've added to the end of the answer. Of course the output is different: You've overridden `Throwable`'s `toString` with your own that does something different.

Answer (score 0):

**Throwable is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language. It has two direct implementations: Error and Exception.
Error is a subclass that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.
Exception indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to catch.**

So, you should not create your custom exceptions implementing Throwable, and you should not catch Throwable, because doing so you are also catching Error type, and Error is not expected to be cached.

It is also worth mentioning that there is a famous subtype of Exception: RuntimeException. RuntimeException are unchecked exceptions, meaning you can throw them and caller is not forced to catch it.

There was a great debate for years about using Exception vs RuntimeException. RuntimeException won (some may still think the contrary of course), but in early days using Exception was considered the king, that is why several Java APIs of first versions throw Exception type, and modern Java APIs and frameworks most of the time throw RuntnimeException.

As for

> What does e actually represent here? I knows it is a reference to SQL exception object but what will it print? Does it call the toString method?

You are right, e is the name of a variable of type SQLException, that you can work with inside catch block. And it does call its toString method as every Object does when added inside a System.out.println().

> Edit : The output I get is very different when I override the toString method and when I remove it entirely from my source code. Please explain why?

In your example you are extending Throwable, as mentioned before, you should not do that. All class extending Throwable will use its toString() implementation, it documentation says:

> /**
>        * Returns a short description of this throwable.
>        * The result is the concatenation of:
>        *
>
>   *
> - the {@linkplain Class#getName() name} of the class of this object
>          *
>
>   ": " (a colon and a space)
>          *
>
>   the result of invoking this object's {@link #getLocalizedMessage}
>          *      method
>          *
>
> * If {@code getLocalizedMessage} returns {@code null}, then just
>        * the class name is returned.
>        *
>        * @return a string representation of this throwable.
>        */
>       public String toString()

So, if you override it, like in your example. You are no longer getting its benefits, your toString() method only prints what you put in it.

Comment: I'm extending throwable and not implementing it. Throwable is a class not an interface.